# How to highlight invisible text when using `visible-mode`?

Tags: faces, highlighting, visibility

I sometime use `visible-mode` to show hidden elements in buffers.
For example, I have `org-hide-emphasis-markers`set to `t`, but I sometimes want to see them. This works very well with `visible-mode`, however the face used for the markers is then the default face. I would like to show all normally invisible text with a special face. At the moment I can only think of utilizing the text property `invisible` in some way, but this would require a function scanning the text and updating on changes... Is there some package available which can fontify text properties?

Answer (score 1):

I found that the [`highlight`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/HighlightLibrary) package can do this, e.g. with `(hlt-highlight-all-prop 'invisible)`.

> **`hlt-highlight-all-prop`** is an interactive Lisp function in
> [`highlight.el`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/highlight.el).
>
> It is bound to **`C-x X h p`**.
>
> `(hlt-highlight-all-prop PROPERTY &optional START END FACE MSGP MOUSEP)`
>
> Highlight all text that has `PROPERTY` (any value), using `FACE`.
>
> Highlight using only overlays.
> Args are the same as for `hlt-highlight-property-with-value`.